# BitmapDrawable cannot be cast to AnimationDrawable

Tags: java, android, eclipse, logcat

I'm working on a app that performs a function once I shake the phone. For this I created a class named ShakeListener. My app works perfectly like its supposed to when I open it. When I open the app and press the back button and go to my home screen and shake the phone it turns on the flash(like it's supposed) but when I open the app again it crashes. I don't know why this is happening

My main activity is

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity   {
 @Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        SharedPreferences getprefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        boolean stopshake = getprefs.getBoolean("checkbox", true);
        if (stopshake) {
            mShaker = new ShakeListener(this); 
            mShaker.setOnShakeListener(new ShakeListener.OnShakeListener () {
                public void onShake() { 
                    if (!isFlashOn && mShaker != null ) {

                        getCamera();
                        turnOnFlash();
                    } else {
                        turnOffFlash();

                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            if (mShaker != null) {
                mShaker.setOnShakeListener(null);
                mShaker = null;
            }
        }    
}

private ToggleButton togle;
 private Camera camera;
    private boolean isFlashOn;

    private boolean hasFlash;
    Parameters params;
    private ShakeListener mShaker;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    ImageView anime;
    int p=1; 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    anime = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Animation);

    hasFlash = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()
            .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);

    if (!hasFlash) {
        // device doesn't support flash
        // Show alert message and close the application
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .create();
        alert.setTitle("Error");
        alert.setMessage("Sorry, your device doesn't support flash light!");
        alert.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // closing the application
                finish();   }
        });
        alert.show();
        return;}


    getCamera();


    togle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.ToggleButton01);

    togle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              boolean checked = ((ToggleButton) v).isChecked();
               if (checked){
                   turnOffFlash();
              }

               else{
                   getCamera();
                   turnOnFlash(); 
               }
                  }
        });


    }

private void getCamera() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (camera == null) {
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
            params = camera.getParameters();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Log.e("Camera Error. Failed to Open. Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }
    } }

private void turnOnFlash() {
    if (!isFlashOn) {
        if (camera == null || params == null) {
            return;
        }
        // play sound
        getCamera();
        playSound();

        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.startPreview();
        isFlashOn = true;
        anime.setImageResource(R.drawable.anim);
        anime.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                AnimationDrawable frameAnimation =
                    (AnimationDrawable) anime.getDrawable(); 
                frameAnimation.start();
            }
        });

        // changing button/switch image
    }
  }

 private void turnOffFlash() {
        if (isFlashOn) {
            if (camera == null || params == null) {
                return;
            }
            // play sound
            playSound();

            params = camera.getParameters();
            params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            camera.setParameters(params);
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
            isFlashOn = false;
            anime.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);
            // changing button/switch image
        }
    }

private void playSound() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     if(isFlashOn){
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.off1);
        }else{
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.on1);
        }
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mp.release();
            }
        }); 
        mp.start();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     switch(item.getItemId()){
     case R.id.action_settings:
         Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Prefsetting.class);
        startActivity(intent);
         break;

     case R.id.about:
         AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
         dlgAlert.setMessage("This is an alert with no consequence");
         dlgAlert.setTitle("App Title");
         dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
         dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
         dlgAlert.create().show();
         break;

 }
 return true;


}   
       }
```

My logcat shows

> 08-23 04:31:53.205: D/ShakeListener(11990): ShakeListener invoked---->
>   08-23 04:31:53.207: D/ShakeListener(11990): ShakeListener setOnShakeListener invoked---->
>   08-23 04:31:53.312: D/AndroidRuntime(11990): Shutting down VM
>   08-23 04:31:53.314: E/AndroidRuntime(11990): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   08-23 04:31:53.314: E/AndroidRuntime(11990): Process: com.shakylight, PID: 11990
>   08-23 04:31:53.314: E/AndroidRuntime(11990): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable
>   08-23 04:31:53.314: E/AndroidRuntime(11990):    at com.shakylight.MainActivity$4.run(MainActivity.java:145)
>   08-23 04:31:53.314: E/AndroidRuntime(11990):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>   08-23 04:31:53.314: E/AndroidRuntime(11990):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>   08-23 04:31:53.314: E/AndroidRuntime(11990):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>   08-23 04:31:53.314: E/AndroidRuntime(11990):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>   08-23 04:31:53.314: E/AndroidRuntime(11990):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   08-23 04:31:53.314: E/AndroidRuntime(11990):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>   08-23 04:31:53.314: E/AndroidRuntime(11990):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>   08-23 04:31:53.314: E/AndroidRuntime(11990):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Comment: Hello ! Please post a short version of your code and read the section on how to ask a question

Comment: Ah I did but I'm afraid this problem requires me to show the complete code. I think my title might lack the accuracy for which I apologize but just couldn't come out with a better one

Comment: The error is here apparently: E/AndroidRuntime(11990): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable 08-23 04:31:53.314: E/AndroidRuntime(11990): at com.shakylight.MainActivity$4.run(MainActivity.java:145). Can't really read your whole code on my phone

Comment: Ah I see, If possible can you please give me a solution. it seems my animation is causing some problem

Comment: You can see my answer for more information. I still think that most of your question does not need this whole bunch of code. The logcat tells you exactly what the problem is so you should have posted just something like that. If my answer provides a solution to your problem, please edit your question anyway so that other people with the same problem can easily identify themselves with your question. I'm editing the title anyway

Comment: weirdly enough didn't get notified for that. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DISCLAIMER: I cannot test what I advise you to try here but it might work just fine. In any case, you can let me know in the comments.

So the error is coming from this line:

```
AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) anime.getDrawable();
```

I'm no expert and the documentation doesn't help. Android documentation example is the following: (see here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html)

```
AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) img.getBackground();
```

However, a thorough search on SO (here=["Class Cast Exception" when trying to set image frames to background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18043504/class-cast-exception-when-trying-to-set-image-frames-to-background)) gave me this where the solution is apparently to do the following (contrary to the logic of the documentation):

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.<your_animation_xml_file_name>)
```

Comment: Yeah the thing is it's giving me an error on "res" from Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.<your_animation_xml_file_name>) apparently it can't resolve it and detect it as a folder

Comment: Have you actually replaced "<your_animation_xml_file_name>" by the actual name of your xml animation file?

Comment: Yes I have replaced it to Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.anim);

Comment: @Blacklotis "res" is probably shorthand for `getResources()`.

Comment: So what is the error you get exactly? Have you tried what the documentation also says ? I cannot test at the moment so I don't actually know which one of them is correct

Comment: @Blacklotis that is totally right, sorry about that and thanks for the edit :).

Comment: Seems my tagging was wrong, it was made for you @PPartisan, i messed up somehow ^^'.

Comment: @Blacklotis does it help? If it does please mark the answer as accepted. If it does not please give us some more feedback in the comments here.

Comment: It doesn't give me the same error but now the animation stopped working and it only displays the first image in the animation xml

Comment: Have you tried the solution I provided thanks to the documentation ?

Comment: Okay so after a few hours of head banging I finally solved the issue, the problem was with public void run(). I just removed that and it works perfectly now

Comment: I'm guessing you had an other issue with the cast that my answer did solve though cause the run problem was not mentioned in your first logcat @Blacklotis. Please mark as accepted then as it helped with this precise part of your question. The other part of the problem was not documented on the question so I could help with that

Answer (score 4):

Problem seems to be coming at following line when you are casting:

```
AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) anime.getDrawable();
```

You are using `anime.setImageResource()` on `ImageView` to set your drawable. Instead try using `anime.setImageDrawable(getResource().getDrawable(R.drawable. anim);` and see if the error still persists.

Comment: Maybe the logcat is different though. Just saying that it still crashed is not enough. Upvote cause it seems logical to me. @Blacklotis check my answer then, it may help you